# Can I use class helpers for TWebActionItem or TWebRequest?

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-xe2

I have some 20+ TWebActionItems with associated OnAction event handlers:

```
procedure TWebModuleWebServices.WebModuleWebServicesTTLoginAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
```

on a TWebModuleWebServices = class(TWebModule). (Note: Sender is a TWebActionItem)

These handlers all have some identical local variables, 'initialization' and 'finalization' code.

I have managed to move some code to AfterDispatch and BeforeDispatch handlers for the TWebModuleWebServices.

If I want to move more common code, I would need store data in (object) variables in the BeforeDispatch (and access these variables in the OnAction handlers and AfterDispatch).

Since AfterDispatch and BeforeDispatch have the same `Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse;` parameters as the OnAction handlers, I'm thinking about writing a class helper for either TWebActionItem or TWebRequest.
Class helpers are not allowed to have data members ("E2169 Field definition not allowed after methods or properties"), but there is a [trick with class vars/constructors/destructors](http://windwings.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/turbocharging-delphi-2010-adding-dynamic-functionality-to-3rd-party-frameworks-read-vcl/).
In this article the author circumvents the fact that class vars are global by using a TDictionary:

```
TPanelHelper2 = class helper for TPanel
public
  class var
    MetaData: TDictionary<TPanel, string>; //store some strings - an example
  procedure PutData(aData: string);
  function ReadData: string;
  class constructor SetUp;
  class destructor TearDown;
end;

implementation

procedure TPanelHelper2.PutData(aData: string);
begin
  MetaData.AddOrSetValue(Self, aData);
end;

function TPanelHelper2.ReadData: string;
begin
  if MetaData.ContainsKey(Self) then
    Result:=MetaData.Items[Self]
  else
    Result:=''; //or whatever
end;

class constructor TPanelHelper2.SetUp;
begin
  MetaData:=TDictionary<TPanel, string>.Create;
end;

class destructor TPanelHelper2.TearDown;
begin
  MetaData.Free;
end;
```

To use this, put 2 panels on a form, then:

```
Panel1.PutData('panel1string');
Panel2.PutData('panel2string');
ShowMessage('Panel 1 metadata: ' + Panel1.ReadData);
ShowMessage('Panel 2 metadata: ' + Panel2.ReadData);
```

A nice trick, but it makes me wonder if I can do this on my TWebModuleWebServices. I do not have enough insight into the internal workings of Delphi (VMT etc) to answer these questions:

1. Is this safe?
2. Is there a better approach (Class helpers have their disadvantages, see e.g. **Class Helpers Go and NoGo** in [Understanding Delphi Class (and Record) Helpers](http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/a/understanding-delphi-class-and-record-helpers.htm))?

**Edit**:
There is an error in the above question:
*Since AfterDispatch and BeforeDispatch have the same Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; parameters as the OnAction handlers*
 is incorrect.
The Sender is a TWebModuleWebservices for the AfterDispath/BeforeDispatch and a TWebActionItem for the OnAction handlers. I'm leaving it in because it would require a big question rewrite and it is not essential to the answer(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These handlers all have some identical local variables

You could also simply turn these local variables into private fields of the web module.

Comment: But the TWebModule is not created for every WebAction, is it?? The local variables would be overwritten. This is a FWebBrokerBridge := TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.Create(Self) with FWebBrokerBridge.RegisterWebModuleClass(TWebModuleWebServices);

Comment: A single request is always processed (through one or more actions) by one instance of the web module. (There may be other instances processing other requests on different threads.) The private fields may be reused by actions - this should be no problem since only one action is executing at a time. I'm assuming stateless server - no state needs to be preserved between requests.

Comment: That simplifies things a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It´s safe, but not necessarely the best option for the problem presented.

In your place I would go for inheritance. I would create a subclass from TWebModule and add all the general functionality all the other TWebModules have in this class. Then I would change the current ancestor of the other TWebModules to be this new one.

The nice thing of the approach is that you can adopt it slowly and carefuly. You can create the base TWebModule for your application, add some behavior to it and choose one single of the other TWebModules to experience the inheritance advantages. You can adapt, redesign and test for the single TWebModule you chose.

After that you can go for another and another until getting all done.